# Showing that $x_n=nx^n$ is a solution of the recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Given that $r^2 - ar - b$ has the double root $x$, how do you show that $x_n = nx^n$ is a solution of $x_{n+1}=-4x_n-4x_{n-1}$?
I can show $x_n$ = $x^n$ but I just can't show for $x_n$ = $nx^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the characteristic equation $f(x)$ be $$f(x)=x^n-c_1x^{n-1}-\cdots -c_kx^{n-k}$$

Since $\alpha$ is a double root, we have $$f(\alpha)=f'(\alpha)=0$$
This gives $$\alpha f'(\alpha) = n\alpha^n-c_1(n-1)\alpha^{n-1} - \cdots -c_k(n-k)\alpha^{n-k}=0$$

Therefore, $n \alpha^n$ is a solution. A triple root, etc can be proved like this as well.

Comment: How do you go from f of alpha equals f dashed of alpha to the last line?

Comment: I differentiated the equation and got that $n \alpha^n - c_1(n-1)\alpha^{n-1} - \cdots c_k(n-k)\alpha^{n-k}=0$. Therefore, if I let $x_n=n\alpha^n$, we have $x_n-c_1x_{n-1}-c_2x_{n-2}- \cdots - c_kx_{n-k}=0$, as desired.

Comment: Ok thanks I understand you now